# How to get date object from moment.js after formatting it

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using typescript, I am formatting my date with moment.js like this.

```
function getCreatedDate(objContainingDate: any): Date {
    // Following line does not work since it is returning string, 
    // I need formatted date object to return 
    return moment(objContainingDate.createdDate).format("L")
}
```

The format method returns a string, how to convert it back to date object ?

Comment: Maybe you can use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/), but I'm not sure I have understood what you want to do. Why you are using `format`? What is the type of `objContainingDate.createdDate`?

Comment: createdDate is of type "Date" but if i just try to use it as it is without  using moment it gives me a value like "2016-07-14T19:58:47.2698161Z" and i dont want that, so when i use format("L") i get it converted to "07/12/2016" but it is string and i need to convert that back to Date. I even tried new Date( moment(objContainingDate.createdDate).format("L") ), but this gives me date object like "Thu Jul 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  You said the input is a `Date` object, and the desired output is a `Date` object - what do you want to do in the middle?  Also, your last comment makes no sense unless you are talking about the result of converting a `Date` object to a `string` (either implicitly or by calling `toString`).  A `Date` object has no format unto itself.

Answer (score 40):

This might be a delayed response.But, I think it can help others who still needs an answer.

https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/

`To retrieve a native Date object from Moment, use .toDate()`

You can directly get the Date object from Moment.

Answer (score 7):

Using the date object with moment clones it and the original object is left intact to continue to use. But to convert it back just pass the formatted moment string into a new date object.

```
var myDateObj = new Date(2011, 9, 16);
var now = moment(myDateObj);
#Now convert it back to date object
var newDateObj = new Date(now.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"));
```

Comment: This is not gonna work in my case, i need formatted object to be converted into date, i have to use that date object somwhere else, it has to be date.

Comment: Sorry about that, I miss understood the question at first.  But the date object can be recreated from the formatted moment string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Yea its not gonna work.  I have created a plunck see if you can make it work there .. http://plnkr.co/edit/uNTngz5aWc2zlg9Q1Jww?p=preview